# Ligatures being applied in iOS's Safari but not on OSX's Safari or Chrome

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser, typography

I'm using the free version of `PT Serif` loaded through Google Fonts, and for a while I thought it didn't had the common ligatures. Until I launched my website on the iPad and found out that it was correctly rendering them. Upon inspection, it seems neither Chrome nor Safari for OSX are rendering them correctly. Chrome for Android is also ignoring them.

Here's a render on Chrome v45 on OSX El Capitan:

[image: Rendered on Chrome v45 on OSX El Capitan]

Note the `fi` in breadth-first search. Now on iOS:

[image]

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
font-family: 'PT Serif', Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
font-size: $base-font-size;
line-height: $base-line-height;
font-weight: 300;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-font-feature-settings: "liga=1, dlig=1";
-ms-font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig";
-webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig";
-o-font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig";
font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig";
font-variant-ligatures: contextual;
```

The font is being loaded in the page header using the following code:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

You can check the [aforementioned webpage here](http://hugoferreira.github.io/fun/mathematics/puzzle/2015/09/22/the-mu-puzzle.html).

Is this some kind of limitation, bug, or is my CSS missing something?

Comment: Fun question: are those the same fonts? Name aside, are they the same version, roughly same size, does the GSUB table say the OSX version actually has the ligature implemented?

Comment: It's an interesting question, but since the font is not usually pre-installed in the system, and I'm using Google Fonts for the import, I'm *assuming* they would be the same.

Comment: Sort of a reasonable assumption, but Google fonts *will* actually serve different CSS based on whether a browser supports WOFF or WOFF2. However, that usually doesn't impact ligature substitutions.

Comment: Your guess of Google fonts being the one misbehaving here was spot on. See me answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Google Fonts is the culprit. Substituting with [Brick](http://brick.im/), I get all the ligatures I was looking for:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//brick.a.ssl.fastly.net/PT+Serif:400,400i,700,700i:f">
```

It remains to be understood why iOS was already rendering it correctly, or why Google Fonts is misbehaving (?)...

Comment: check out the network traffic for each device to see which actual font resource they get - might be worth finding out and blogging about.